# Hide commands in Python's cmd module

Tags: python, cmd

I'm writing a command line tool based on Python's `cmd` module (actually, `cmd2`, but they're pretty similar). This tool connects to an REST API which requires authentication; each user has his own privilege level (think admin and regular user).

In my Python code I'm creating a do_* method corresponding to each method of the API. That means I'll end up with things like `do_an_admin_command` and `do_regular_user_command` which will be callable by anyone running the tool, no matter of the privilege level of his user.

What I need is a way to hide every admin command available in the Python tool, if the user is not privileged. You can assume the tool knows at start up what credentials to use to authenticate to the API and whether the user is privileged or not; also, the administrative commands are a superset of the regular ones.

Any ideas?

Comment: Admin command of what? The REST API? Your tool?

Comment: Explained the problem a little better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use subclassing to your advantage:

```
class RegularShell(cmd.Cmd):
    do_search(self, arg):
        ...
    do_retrieve(self, arg):
        ...

class AdminShell(RegularShell):
    do_update(self, arg):
        ...
```

With the REST API, connect privileged users to the AdminShell and others to the RegularShell.

Another alternative to consider is using the *precmd* hook to see check for authorization.

Comment: +1. One could also make the `AdminShell` a subclass of `RegularShell` to get all the features of the latter in the former.

Comment: Subclassing will work for me if I do something like class `AdminShell(RegularShell)`  (since admin cmds are a superset of the regular cmds), but that's not very convenient given the layout of my current code. Will using `precmd` allow me to prevent the admin commands from being displayed in help also? Because I'd like that also.

Comment: With the precmd approach, you should also override the help method to do what you want.

Comment: Ok it seems to work but it will also require overriding do_help and stuff like that. Too bad a feature like this is not there out of the box.